# Match home.jsp in RegEx and not For-The-Home.jsp

Tags: regex

I have a RegEx:

```
^\/\z|home.jsp
```

I don't want it to match `for-the-home.jsp` but I do want it to match `home.jsp`

I've tried:

```
^\/\z|!for\-the\-home\.jsp|^\/\z|home.jsp
```

Comment: What is the `/z` part?  Why are you trying to match `/z`?  I don't see anything involving `/z` in your example of `for-the-home.jsp`..

Comment: \z matches end of string.

Comment: Oh ok, yes I see, sorry, I've just always used `$`, but now I see there's a difference..

Comment: How about just simply, `[^-]+.jsp`

Comment: What kind of regular expressions implementation are you using? Java? Python?

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe in your original regex you simply meant to include parentheses: `^(\/\z|home.jsp)`. Otherwise, `^` would only be associated with the first half, matching `^\/\z` or `home.jsp`. Thus why it currently matches the latter half of "for-the-home.jsp" because it's not anchored with `^`.

Comment: It's the Ruby regular expression engine.  Can be checked at http://rubular.com

Comment: @Wiseguy thanks!  Wrapping the home.jsp in () fixed it.  If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  Also thanks for editing my question as well.  It's been a while since I asked a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what your looking for:

```
((?<![\w-])home\.jsp|\/$)
```

This regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/oI3vD7

the regex searches for `home.jsp` but uses a negative lookbehind assertion to make sure that any other word character or - does not precede `home.jsp` OR it matches the alternative of just `/`.